# The 'ol Error: Could not find or load main class os x

Tags: java, classloader, manifest

I have a program with packages and dependent jars I'm trying to run.  I've tried by executable jar but have fallen back to just using bash.

*** Yes I have read the multitude of stackoverflow articles on this ***

Most said examples refer to simple flat projects

```
project
 + libs/                     # all my external depends
 + src/main/java/com/blah    # files
 + target/classes            # where I create the class files.
```

Yes, this is a Jersey servlet.  From the command line I run:

```
   export BIGGIE='./:./target/classes/com/blah/*:libs/activation-1.1.jar:libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.10.jar:libs/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:libs/jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.10.jar:libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar:libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:libs/jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar:libs/jersey-bundle-1.19.4.jar:libs/jersey-common-2.27.jar:libs/jersey-entity-filtering-2.27.jar:libs/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.27.jar:libs/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:libs/servlet-api-2.5.jar:libs/stax-api-1.0-2.jar'

    java -verbose -cp $BIGGIE com.blah.Main

    and receive the error Error: Could not find or load main class com.blah.Main.
```

And lots of library loaded messages NONE of which are my libs if that is significant.

I've tried using all variants of the Main class package name.   I tried moving all the class files into the libs dir,etc.

This all runs fine when run from intellij, but I need a standalone version I can run from a Makefile.   Don't ask why.

Mucho thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to your folder stops at the folder containing "com". Change your `BIGGIE` declaration, the part that currently says `./target/classes/com/blah/*` should just be `./target/classes/`

Comment: Thank you, cleared it right up.   And brought me to my next blocker, :)